# Can TFS validate file content and reject / give warning?

Tags: tfs

The way we use TFS is that in our development tool we export all classes of the project into one XML and manually upload that XML as the new version to our TFS project. However sometimes the export process includes classes that must **not** be in that export.

Can TFS validate the content of the upload and give a warning that the file contains illegal strings, such as "class this.that.shared.never_include_this_in_exports()"?

Comment: This is what continuous integration is for. Write tests. Run tests during CI. Don't allow a merge if the tests fail.

Comment: Implementing proper CI process in our company is not an option at the moment, thus I was asking this specific technical question...

Comment: The specific technical question you asked is best solved via CI. Can you accomplish it other ways? Probably, but not easily. The best path forward is to use industry-standard patterns and practices that are *designed* to solve this kind of technical problem

Answer (score 0):

> Can TFS validate file content and reject / give warning?

AFAIK, I do not think TFS supports validate file content feature when we upload it to the repo.

For TFS, whether it is a centralized TFVC or a distributed git, TFS only tracks and controls the file itself, and does not provide verification of the syntax in the file. This should be a function of our compiler. It should not be a function of a version control tool.

So we need to use other tools locally to verify whether there are any errors in our XML, or, as Daniel said, to verify whether the file is correct through CI.